# c# substring from a word in quotes

Tags: c#, substring, quotes

I am trying to use substring to get a value from a string as such:

```
surname='Smith',name="John"
```

I basically want to use the text "name" and the quotes to get the value "John"..

Is there a way to do this please?

Comment: Use [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use linq query to get name

```
   var query = @"surname='Smith',name = \""John\""";

        var name = query
            .Split(',')
            .Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                s.Split('=').GetValue(0).ToString().Trim(),
            s.Split('=').GetValue(1).ToString().Trim()
        )) 
        .FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == "name").Value;

        Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.
That is one:

```
char[] quotes = { '\'', '\"' };
string input = "surname='Smith',name=\"John\"";
string[] sections = input.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < sections.Length; i++)
{ 
    string[] pair = sections[i].Split('=');
    
    if (pair[0] == "surname")
        Debug.WriteLine("surname=" + pair[1].Trim(quotes));

    if (pair[0] == "name")
        Debug.WriteLine("name=" + pair[1].Trim(quotes));
}
```